# ACE editor in smartphone browser

Tags: javascript, android, css, editor, ace-editor

I want to display & edit code from my Android phone browser.

I have successfully embedded [ACE Editor](http://ace.c9.io/) to edit code from my laptop browser. But there are som problems when I try to edit code from an android phone.

1. I can't scroll in the editor
2. I cant make the editor to adapt size to
       code
3. The editor won't show up when i try to add no-scale in head: `<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.6667, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />`

http://jsbin.com/cabic/6/edit

Comment: I tried codemirror instead and had none of the problems above. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

very basic scrolling (without animations) was added in v1.2.0
use maxLines option to make editor adapt to the size of code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="description" content="ACE Highlighter" />

<title>ACE in Action</title>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Testing</h2>

<div id="editor" style="width:600px;height:300px;">
&lt;script&gt;alert("Hiiiiii!");&lt;/script&gt;</div>
  
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/ace/1.2.0/min/ace.js"
             type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>  
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setOptions({
      theme: "ace/theme/twilight",
      minLines: 2,
      maxLines: 50
    });
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/php");
    editor.resize(true);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```